# Host a websocket server in Angular

Tags: javascript, android, angular, websocket

Is it possibile to communicate between a Browser (Running Angular) with an Android phone without a server? Is there a way to host a Websocket Service in Angular or JavaScript where I can connect with the Android App? Or is a websocket not the solution for my problem? This communication should only work in a private network!
What would you recommend?

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: (1) I'm not sure you can have any kind of a listening socket in a web app. (2) You can have a listening socket in an Android app, but it does not strike me as a very good idea: how do you find it? will your device have a routable IP, or be behind NAT? do you want your app to prevent the device form sleeping to make it available for connecting?

Comment: 2) I know but hosting the websocket on android causes some other problems, so I thought maybe I cloud do that in Anguar... Simply they will know it! You have to input the private IP of the host and yes it is behing a NAT (both of them) - no I just want to comunicate for a few seconds

Comment: I don't think Angular has anything to do with that. I'd run a proper listening server where you serve your Angular app, be it a server you already have, or a local server on the same machine where the web app runs. I'd not try to do it from the browser. Or you can use something like socket.io. There are lots of reasons to prevent a web app from having a listening socket.

Comment: But I cant host a local server from a browser so the only solution would be to have one external. So there is no way to build a direct connetion in a private network with Angular and Android? Also in other technologies?

Comment: I think you can't use a _web browser_ as an IP server directly. It appears though that WebSockets and WebRTC support listening on the browser side, but _as far as I know_ you still need to register with an external server first. Where do you host your Angular app — do you plan to open it from the local filesystem?